# Changing the default JRE a browser uses to launch applets

Tags: java

I have java 6 and java 7 installed and would like all browsers to use java 6 to launch applets, and not java 7. I went to control panel -> java -> view, added the javaw.exe file which is in the JRE6\bin folder, and checked it as "enabled" and un-checked jre7. But still, when i launch an applet the dll's used are from the JRE7 folder.

Comment: Why do you want to use the jre 6 instead of jre 7?

Comment: @tmarwen Probably because the new jre 7 does not allow you to start unsigned applets!?